# NSUserDefaults from AppGroup is empty in Watch App

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app has the following targets:

- iOS App
- Today Extension
- Apple Watch App
- Apple Watch Extension

All of these targets have the "App Group" capability with the correct group selected.  In the main iOS app, I synchronize the settings like so:

```
NSUserDefaults * sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]initWithSuiteName:@"group.foo.bar"];
if([sharedDefaults respondsToSelector:@selector(setObject:forKey:)]){
    // Example Value
    [sharedDefaults setObject:@"TestString" forKey:@"TestString"];
    [sharedDefaults synchronize];
}
```

The Today Extension uses the following to get the settings, which works just fine:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.foo.bar"];
NSLog(@"String: %@", [defaults stringForKey:@"TestString"]);
// String: TestString
```

The watch extension uses the same line of code to get the settings as the today extension, however it does not work.  In the console I see `String: (null)`.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create your watch target as a watchOS WatchKit Application (watchOS 2) or as an iOS Application Extension (watchOS 1)? If targeting for watchOS 2, according to the [transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/index.html): `You cannot rely on a shared group container to exchange files with your iOS app. Fetching files involves transferring them wirelessly to Apple Watch.`

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [settings bundle not working on watchOS 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32638667/) Apparently the docs are not that clear on what can and cannot be done with Preferences, the only way I found was to ensure that I copy the required user defaults over and keep them synced manually ([NSUserDefaults not working on Xcode beta with Watch OS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851729/nsuserdefaults-not-working-on-xcode-beta-with-watch-os2/32628105#32628105)).